# Why does not ref int value change from the original value in C# 7.3?

Tags: c#

I have following code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var x = 9;
        var y = 23;
        Console.WriteLine($"x = {x}, y = {y}");

        var z = SomeMethod(ref x, y);

        Console.WriteLine($"x = {x}, y = {y}, z = {z}");

        z = 20;
        Console.WriteLine($"x = {x}, y = {y}, z = {z}");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static ref int SomeMethod(ref int x, int y)
    {
        x++;
        y++;
        return ref x;
    }
```

Please note the **ref** on the method return signature of SomeMethod.

This produces following output:

```
x = 9, y = 23
x = 10, y = 23, z = 10
x = 10, y = 23, z = 20
```

I was expecting the value of x on the last line to be same as z value. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/ref-returns), when you do this:

```
int z = SomeMethod(ref x, y);
```

You are only keeping the value returned by `SomeMethod` (giving that structs, such as `int`, are value types).

What you are looking for is the [`ref local`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/ref-returns) feature, which is achieved by the following:

```
ref int z = ref SomeMethod(ref x, y);
```

Then, when you modify `z`, you are actually modifying `x`:

```
x = 9, y = 23
x = 10, y = 23, z = 10
x = 20, y = 23, z = 20
```

Answer (score 4):

You are missing that we are not talking objects or pointers.

You simple set the value of `z` to `20`. That has nothing to do with the refs you copied around.